# Spring AOP ordering - Transactions before Advise

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop

I am writing some Advice and I want the Transactions to commit before it gets to the advice.  It seems to work for Save and Delete, but when I update, it runs thorough the advice, and then throws the exception.

```
try {
    retVal = pjp.proceed();
} catch (Exception e) {
    PSPSFaultException fault = new PSPSFaultException(e);
    pmLog.error(ERR_MSG, fault);
    throw fault;
}
```

As you can see here, I am trying to Wrap the exceptions in our own Runtime exception.

I tried ordering:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" order="1"/>
```

and

```
@Around( "execution(* blah.blah.PersistenceProvider.*(..))")
@Order(value=2)
public Object persistenceWrapper(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
```

but this does not seem to make any difference in the stack or functionality.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class PersistenceProviderImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements  PersistenceProvider {

@Override
public void update(Object o) {
    this.getHibernateTemplate().update(o);
}
```

Is there a way to get the update to fire before the advice?  The transactions are at the dao level...

Comment: Specifically, my test is updating something that is not on the database.  I get a HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException error...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so you are doing 2 things wrong:

1. You should have smaler value near your advices and bigger value near
   your transaction manager (higher priority for advices, executed
   first - lower priority for transaction manager, executed later)
2. Yous should put `@Order(1)` annotation in front of whole `@Aspect` class (strange, but it works for me)

Something like this:

```
...
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" order="200"/>  
...
@Order(1)
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
...
```

Comment: Just to clarify, from the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) _Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from ```Ordered.getValue()``` (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence._

Comment: This is evident in the ```Ordered``` interface too: ```int HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.MIN_VALUE;```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the above advice was not working. I'm using compile time weaving with the Maven, so this might be the reason.

My goal was to handle database exceptions after the transaction was finished and wrap them into another exception.

I had to include in one of the Aspect files (I guess which one does not matter):

```
@DeclarePrecedence(value = "*..*TransactionException*,     org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect, *..*Logging*, *")
```