# Spring AOP: @AfterThrowing execution pointcut never matches

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I'm completely new to AOP. I need advice to write the correct pointcut. I have a service package that contains all service classes. All the classes implement the `Service` interface. This interface has a method `save(entity)`. My advice should be executed every time the `service.save(entity)` method throws a `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Here the aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class DIVExceptionHandler {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myPackage.service.Service.save(*))", throwing = "ex")
        public void handleException(JoinPoint joinPoint, DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        //snipped
    }
}
```

I have both aspectj jars in the CP as explained in [Spring AOP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) and I have added `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to Spring configuration and I'm using component scanning. In the log of the test I can see that the aspect is detected as aspetcj aspect:

```
DEBUG o.s.a.a.a.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method...
```

So I believe this is not a configuartion issue and my pointcut expression is wrong. I also tried

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myPackage.service.*.save(*))", throwing = "ex")
```

But that did also not work.

So what is the correct pointcut expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it in fact was a configuration issue.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myPackage.service.Service.save(*))", throwing = "ex")
```

Works fine.

The actual problem was that `DataIntegrityViolationException` is only thrown after the proxy for `@Transactional` completes the transaction. In my case this happened after my advice can be called.

The solution is to add an order attribute to transaction configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order="2000"/>
```

And then add an `@Order` annotation to your aspect that is smaller than the one for the transaction:

```
@Component
@Order(1500) // must be less than order of <tx:annotation-driven />
@Aspect
public class DIVExceptionHandler {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myPackage.service.Service.save(*))", throwing = "ex")
        public void handleException(JoinPoint joinPoint, DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        //snipped
    }
}
```

See:

[Spring AOP ordering - Transactions before Advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022235/spring-aop-ordering-transactions-before-advise)